# Heat loss through window vs. holes

Tags: insulation, windows, heating, heat

I'm renovating an old house, and I need to prioritize my work. Let's say we have three heat losses to be compared:

- an old 2,00 x 1,00 meters single glazed window
- a recent 2,00 x 1,00 meters window, with 2022 double-glazing standard
- all little spaces around doors cumulate to the equivalent of a 1 cm² hole between indoor and outdoor.

**How can we calculate the heat loss in Watts for these three?**

Hypothesis: let's say 20°C indoor, and 0°C outdoor, and a constant very light wind (in Europe) (might be needed for the computation of the air through hole).

Comment: The holes will let cold air in, but easy and cheap fix is expanding foam for windows/doors to stop it.  Temporary fix for the single is a window insulation kit, some thin clear plastic held on with tape.  The double can be left or also have the insulation kit put on.

Comment: You can go on line and find R-values for the single & double glazed windows.  From that, the area of the window, and an assumed inside/outside temperature difference, you can calculate the heat loss in watts.  Note that single pane windows have an R-value (US, or Imperial units) of ~1, while a double paned window has an R-value of ~2.  So a double paned windows will lets half as much heat escape as a single paned window.

Comment: The heat loss through holes or gaps is harder to quantify.

Comment: start by measuring temperature near the sources, will give you a initial guidance what to fix first.

Comment: @crip659 Would you have an image about "expanding foam for windows" (I know similar stuff, but out of curiosity, I'm interested about how it's packaged/sold/marketed in other countries from France). Same question about the "insulation kit", I know adhesive plastic film here, I wonder if it's similar.

Comment: @SteveSh How could we quanity this, if we assume very slow wind (0.5 or 1 km/h) ?

Comment: The expanding foam usually sold in spray cans.  The insulation kits are more like cling film food wrap held on the wall with two sided tape.

Comment: @Basj - I'm not sure.  Heat loss through an air leak, or air exchange with the outside, is a different mechanism than conductive heat loss through a material, like a windows or a wall.

Comment: @crip659 This is the expanding foam I know: https://www.familyhandyman.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/shutterstock_225715105.jpg?fit=700,700. It works for holes between the frame of the window and the wall, but I don't think it will work between the frame and the (moving) window. Does it work?

Comment: Maybe assume some small R-vale for the air in the gap (say 0.1 Imperial units) and calculate the heat loss like any other surface?  This is probably going to be small compared to a window because the area of the opening  (1 sq cm you said) is small.

Comment: The insulation kit will seal the window up for the colder seasons, but does not allow the window to be open when it is on.

Comment: You might want to give that stuff the "smoke test".  Most expanding foam is explosively flammable, and emits incapacitating fumes.  The cyanides or cyanates in the fumes muddle your motor control and you can't walk anymore, and they find your bodies halfway between bedroom and exit door.  This is called "smoke inhalation" - it's a relatively new cause-of-death in fires due to all the plastic krap in homes.

Comment: Air-sealing is the single most effective thing you can do to improve HVAC efficiency. Ideally whoever you bring in will do a proper test with a blower door to determine where the leaks are and fix them.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't know about the maths, but air leakage and drafts in general are definitely your first priority. Air movement and exchange with the outdoors will be the most uncomfortable and most defeating of your energy efficiency.

A cheap can of Spray Foam or a Tube of Caulk is great only where they can squirt into.

While Weatherstripping around leaky doors and windows is the best solution there.

And, Plastic Sheeting over leaky doors or windows is the worst, as it stops usage of whatever it's applied over and only seals out drafts temporarily. It doesn't last nor stay stuck-up even for a year...usually.

Comment: Thanks @Iggy! Being curious, as I'm not a native English speaker, is "Tube of Caulk" the same thing as silicone cartridge? Or is it slightly different?

Comment: Yes, silicone cartridge or the smaller use toothpaste types that you just squeeze out without any gun or other device.

Comment: Ok. Caulk and silicone are the same thing @Iggy?

Comment: Yep, they're usually just called sealants, but most people don't get that. They can be silicone based or latex based, silicone lasts much longer.

Comment: Caulk/caulking is a flexible substance used to fill and smooth over small gaps. Silicone-based caulk is one of the more common types, but there are other formulations which have their own advantages and disadvantages.